# Possibility of achieving Envers audit in asynchronous manner

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I added Envers into my project and audit tables are updating on entity creating/updating transactions. perfect!!

Now I want the execution of audit table updating transaction in an asynchronous manner. What I'm trying to achieve is - even though auditing transaction fails, main transaction should not be rolled back.

If any one tried this before, please give some hints.

Comment: Please provide some code that yields into any problem. SO is not a "write my code" platform.

Comment: I am not stuck with any code error, I am asking for some hints if anybody has tried before. I searched envers wiki and they are saying it is synchronous and audit happens at the end of transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, it simply isn't possible.  Envers hooks into the default Hibernate event system that fires all listeners in synchronous fashion.

Logically, it makes no sense to flag an entity to be audited and having it's state maintained as a historical record of change and yet allow the entity to be changed regardless of whether it's historical record of change works or not.  This speaks more to a design or deployment problem overall than anything else.

I would say with how Envers and Hibernate are integrated, if you need asynchronous, non-reliable auditing, then it's probably a case of where you need to write your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your AuditEventListener for version 3. After v4 there are different classes for each event type so you you have to have a class for each (org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl etc), but other than that it's no different.

Here's how the code with version 3 looks like:

```
public class MyEventListener extends org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    @Override
    public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
        super.onPostInsert(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate(final PostUpdateEvent event) {
        Runnable runIt = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Running in a thread now");
                MyEventListener.super.onPostUpdate(event);
                System.out.println("Finished OnPostUpdate THREAD!!!!");
            }
        };
        executorService.submit(runIt);
        System.out.println("Finished OnPostUpdate call");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostDelete(PostDeleteEvent event) {
        super.onPostDelete(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreUpdateCollection(PreCollectionUpdateEvent event) {
        super.onPreUpdateCollection(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreRemoveCollection(PreCollectionRemoveEvent event) {
        super.onPreRemoveCollection(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostRecreateCollection(PostCollectionRecreateEvent event) {
        super.onPostRecreateCollection(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: With this code how you can make it async. As in one transaction only it will save in audit table